# How to update a mailchimp template automatically using node.js

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, gulp, mailchimp

How do I update a mailchimp template automatically using node.js.

So if I changed the index.html from the github email repo, it would update the mailhimp template inside mailchimp itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you won't be able to update a MailChimp template from Node.js just by editing a html file in a github repo.

You'll have to use the MailChimp API. You can access the API's directly or you can use one of the MailChimp API wrappers for Node.js. **mailchimp-api-node** is the official MailChimp wrapper, but I use **node-mailchimp**

Depending on what you're updating, the two API's you should look into are:

**/campaigns/template-content** to just update the content portion of the template https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/campaigns/template-content.php

**/templates/update** to update your user templates (not campaign content) to be used in campaigns https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/templates/update.php

Note: These are version 2.0 API's. I haven't had a chance to work with the new version 3.0 API's yet so there may be changes. Version 2.0 API's still work but they just aren't being updated anymore.